# why does pync .notify for mac not work? (python)

Tags: python, macos, notifications

I'm trying to do notifications in python on mac. I have installed pync, and used the following code:

```py
from plyer import notification
import pync, time

while True:
    pync.notify("lets do something random!")
    print("Activated!")
    time.sleep(1)
```

The visual studio code debugger shows this:

```
Activated!
Activated!
Activated!
```

However, no notification shows up. I have enabled notifications, with banner and sounds. Why does the notification not display? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works for me on MacOS 12.3.1

Make sure you have notification from **terminal-notifier** allowed:

System Preferences -> Notifications & Focus -> terminal-notifier
and allow the notifications

Also, it might be the case that you have notifications disabled on your mac e.g. you're in "focus" mode

[image: screenshot of settings]

Comment: the notifications are on, but it still doesn't display notifications. Can you add a screenshot with the terminal-notifier notification settings?

Comment: @mm4096 I've just added it!

Comment: I did your settings, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @mm4096 Is your macOS version newer than 10?

Comment: version is 12.3, so yes

Comment: @mm4096 it also didn't display notifications for me because my Mac was in "work" mode, other than that I'm not sure what went wrong

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244788/discussion-between-mm4096-and-monk).